# Stochastic independence is preserved for linear combinations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Consider two random vectors $X\equiv (X_1,..., X_M)$ and $V\equiv (V_1,..., V_N)$. Suppose that $X\perp V$, where $\perp$ denotes stochastic independence.

Does this imply $W\equiv (X_1-X_M, X_2-X_M,..., X_{M-1}-X_{M})\perp V$?

Comment: Yes.  It should be easy to prove.